# What is the Optimal approuch to check devices availability from Server

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working on a *chat Application* like **Telegram**. The user should see his/her friend **availability** (Online/Offline). I searched a lot and found out that the server must send **ping** to the devices and devices **reply** back. But I think it prevents the app to use the server and device resources optimally. You suppose there are a million of users, lots of pings in every interval, lots of device battery and bandwidth use and so on.

I also studied Firebase and GCM. They check device availability to send messages to them, but I can't use it to show it to the users.

I'm really interested in technology that Telegram used for users availability.

Please let me find an optimal way.
Thanks

Comment: I think [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html) is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @AndréKool Thanks, it was really useful. Do you have any Idea if how to implement it on my own server?

Comment: Regarding your now-deleted question, check `dmesg` to see if Apache has been killed by the system due to lack of memory. You can also do `ps aux | grep httpd` to see if Apache is still running (I think Centos uses "httpd" rather than "apache").

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [the blog post @Andre linked](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html) to, you'll see that the "official" Firebase approach to this problem is to store a value in Firebase's Realtime Database that indicates the status of the user. So, the logic is this:

- use a property in the database to keep track of a user's status (e.g. /users/{uid}/status)
- when a user logs in you set their status to "online"
- when the user logs off/puts the app to the background/is idle you change the value of that 'status' property (e.g. to "offline" (use .onDisconnect() method as shown in the blog post).

Now, whenever you fetch the value of that status it'll always reflect the user's online/offline status without relying on the user actually being online at the time.

If you want to show a user the status of all their friends you simply loop through a list of their friends' uid's and get the relevant status for each. All the info/code seems to be [in that blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html).

Comment: Oh, thanks @James; is there any common approach that I can use which is independent of Firebase? I mean I can use it on my server?

Comment: @MustafaMohammadi I'm not sure I understand. Why don't you want to use Firebase?

Comment: Actually I try to get families with the problems and the solutions. The Firebase is really a great server, and every thing is is ready and I think it makes me lazy. What do you think? Thanks

Comment: @MustafaMohammadi it seems like you're trying to make life too difficult. Just use Firebase (push messages onto the user's node so you don't have to even use FCM!)...nothing wrong with using great products to make your life easier :-)